# VBA Userform not filled when first opened (possible memory issues)

Tags: vba, excel, memory-leaks, userform

VBA'ers,

I'll cut to the chase.  I have a userform with all the bells and whistles(Label's,textboxes,listboxes,tabstrips,etc.).  Currently I have three subs.

Here's my code.  I know people only asked for the userform initialize but seeing all of it might help find the problem.

```
Private x As Single
Private y As Single
'------------------------------------------
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Unload Me

End Sub
'------------------------------------------
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

    x = 2
    y = 2

    name = ListBox1.Value

    'Loop to match names
    Do Until name = Cells(x, y)
        x = x + 1
    Loop

    'Changes lables on click <- I realize I can handle this better with listbox.values
    Label2.Caption = Sheet2.Cells(x, 2)  'Name
    Label5.Caption = Sheet2.Cells(x, 3)  'Current Positions
    Label7.Caption = Sheet2.Cells(x, 4)  'Previous Positions
    Label9.Caption = Sheet2.Cells(x, 5)  'DOB
    Label11.Caption = Sheet2.Cells(x, 6) 'POB
    Label13.Caption = Sheet2.Cells(x, 7) 'Party Affiliation

    'Changes tab strip accordingly
    Call TabStrip1_Change

    'Handles Picture
    If Cells(x, 8) <> "" Then
        Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & Cells(x, 8))
    Else
        Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "..\pics\nophoto.jpg")
    End If

End Sub
'------------------------------------------
Private Sub TabStrip1_Change()

    'Handle Tab Strip
    If TabStrip1.Value = 0 Then
        TextBox1.Value = Cells(x, 9)
    ElseIf TabStrip1.Value = 1 Then
        TextBox1.Value = Cells(x, 10)
    Else
        TextBox1.Value = Cells(x, 11)
    End If

End Sub
'------------------------------------------
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    'Initialize global variables
    x = 2

    'Initialize lists within userform.
    ListBox1.RowSource = "B2:B11"

    'Set tab strip to first tab.
    TabStrip1.Value = 0                  
    TextBox1.Value = Sheet2.Cells(2, 9)

    'Grab photo if path is in cell
    If Cells(2, 8) <> "" Then
        Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & Cells(2, 8))
    Else
        Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "..\pics\nophoto.jpg")
    End If

End Sub
```

The problem is that when I run the code, via vba or a commandButton (Userform1.show) its a coins flip on whether or not the userform populates the listbox.  The labels are initialized correctly, but the listbox shows no text.  If I continue to run and stop the macro, it will eventually work fine.

Is this a memory issue?  Am I not activating the userform properly?  Or is this due to sloppy coding?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Let's cut to the chase :p... Show us your `Userform_Initialize()` or `Activate` code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we cannot see the full `Userform_Initialize()`, I assume you have only populated the list into listbox.

If you want a listbox to select something when it shows, you need to call something like `ListBox1.ListIndex = 0` or the index of your default value. This must be after the list is populated.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks, I believe when it doesn't work, it's because the activesheet is not where you have the list items. Either put in full formula address or Range Name my test workbook is "Test.xlsm":

`ListBox1.RowSource = "[Test.xlsm]Sheet1!B2:B11"` ' Change Workbook and Sheet name to fit yours

or

`ListBox1.RowSource = "Test.xlsm!MyListItems"` ' Change Workbook name, Create and Change the name of the Range that contains the list items.

Comment: @AustinA Change the RowSource to proper address or direct it to a Named Range will fix it. When the list is blank, I believe the sheet that "B2:B11" you refers is not the active one.